# View is not updated when the data is changed with ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I want to change rate parameter and display in ForEach.

```swift
// ViewModel.swift

@MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let serviceContainer: ServiceContainerProtocol

    @Published var funds: [FundModel] = []
    ...

    init(serviceContainer: ServiceContainerProtocol) {
        self.serviceContainer = serviceContainer

        Task { await getFunds() }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

```swift
// FundView.swift

struct FundView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(serviceContainer: ServiceContainerProtocol) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(serviceContainer: serviceContainer))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { 
            VStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.funds, id: \.fundCode) { fund in
                    VStack {
                        Text(String(fund.rate))

                        Button("Add 5") {
                            if let index = viewModel.funds.firstIndex(where: { $0.fundCode == fund.fundCode }) {
                                viewModel.funds[index].rate += 5
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I use Struct for model, view did updated as expected.

```swift
// FundModel.swift

struct FundModel: Decodable {
    let fundCode: String
    ...

    // Internal - Not related to api.
    var rate: Int = 0
    ...

    // MARK: CodingKeys

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fundCode
        ...
    }

    // MARK: Decodable

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        fundCode = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fundCode)
        ...
    }
}
```

If I use Class for model, view did not updated.

```swift
// FundModel.swift

final class FundModel: Decodable {
    let fundCode: String
    ...

    // Internal - Not related to api.
    var rate: Int = 0
    ...

    // MARK: CodingKeys

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fundCode
        ...
    }

    // MARK: Decodable

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        fundCode = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .fundCode)
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to use Class for model because it needs to be inherit some properties from some Super Class.

What is the difference between Struct model and Class model for SwiftUI perspective and why view did not update when I use Class model over Struct model?

Note: FundModel conforms Equtable and Hashable somewhere else.

Comment: Theres a couple of major issues here - in Swift our models are usually structs and in SwiftUI we never view model objects because the View struct is the data model for the actual UIViews that SwiftUI creates and updates for us and the property wrappers give these structs the same reference semantics you get with view model objects. You can learn about structs vs objects here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes and to learn SwiftUI View data structs there are many WWDC videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach using `class ViewModel: ObservableObject {...}` (without the `@MainActor`) and `viewModel.objectWillChange.send()`
as in this example code:

```
 struct FundView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel

    init(serviceContainer: ServiceContainerProtocol) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel(serviceContainer: serviceContainer))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.funds, id: \.fundCode) { fund in
                    VStack {
                        Text(String(fund.rate))

                        Button("Add 5") {
                            if let index = viewModel.funds.firstIndex(where: { $0.fundCode == fund.fundCode }) {
                                viewModel.objectWillChange.send() // <-- here
                                viewModel.funds[index].rate += 5
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

final class FundModel: Decodable {
    let fundCode: String
    var rate: Int = 0

   //....
}
```

Comment: I added only viewModel.objectWillChange.send() and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: great, if my answer provided a solution to your question, could you mark it as correct please, using the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

The view updates when the `@Published var` changes. Your `@Published var` is an array of `FundModel`.

A struct is not a mutable entity, so when you use a `struct`, the array actually replaces the object with a new one. The system recognises the change in the array and publishes it to the view.

A class is mutable, so when you change the rate inside the class, you still have the *same* instance. So, the array of `FundModel` does not change: it still contains exactly the same elements inside, even though one of the elements have changed an internal variable.

The `@Published` wrapper cannot detect that an internal variable of the members of the array has changed: it detects only when the array has different elements inside.

Conclusion: `struct` needs to create a new element to change, `@Published` recognises this. `class` can change, so for `@Published` the object is still the same (the array didn't change).

Comment: I understand thank you. How can I use class over model then?

Comment: @Bahadir: I can't give you *the* solution, but a couple of ideas, you need to check if any of those work for your code. I personally use option B. Option A) Make `FundModel` an `ObservableObject` that publishes the `rate`, then move the `VStack` that's inside the `ForEach` to another view, that observes `FundModel` - it requires some elaboration with bindings. Option B) I prefer using Core Data, which creates observable objects that update the views; also, Core Data objects are persistent. Otherwise, instead of class inheritance, you may think of using structs and protocols(that's a big leap).